# How to return autocomplete result to spring mvc controller using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to return to the controller the selection from the autocomplete. Currently the autocomplete is working fine. I'm getting from my db the results to the form I need. The thing is I want also to pass this result to the controller to do some extra work with it.

So my **controller** looks like this:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/autoCompleteAirportInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, List<AirportInfo>> autoCompleteAirportInfoListAirports(@ModelAttribute("flight")FlightInfo flightInfo) {
        Map<String, List<AirportInfo>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<AirportInfo> airportList = airportService.findAll();
        map.put("airportList", airportList);
        return map;
}

@PostMapping("/autoCompleteAirportInfo")
public String post(@ModelAttribute("flight") FlightInfo flightInfo) {
    return "index";
}
```

the **index.html** thymeleaf containing the .js:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#searchAirports" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/autoCompleteAirportInfo",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        maxRows: 6,
                        startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.airportList, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.city + ", " + item.country + ", " + item.code + ", " + item.name,
                                value: item.city + ", " + item.country + ", " + item.code + ", " + item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            open: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
            },
            close: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
            }
        });
    });
```

and the **form**:

```
<form form ACTION="#" th:action="@{/autoCompleteAirportInfo}" th:object="${flight}" method="post">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="searchAirports"  placeholder="Search:"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want the selected airport value in the controller?

Comment: Yes. So when the user selects the airport and it’s values( airport’s country , city, code etc. ) are shown in the text field, I want this airport to be returned as object to the controller also.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried by setting up some sample as below.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/autoCompleteAirportInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, List<AirportInfo>> autoCompleteAirportInfoListAirports() {
        List<AirportInfo> list = new ArrayList<AirportInfo>();
        AirportInfo airportInfo = new AirportInfo("A","B","C","D");
        list.add(airportInfo);
        airportInfo = new AirportInfo("E","F","G","H");
        list.add(airportInfo);   
        map.put("airportList", list);
        return map;
}

@RequestMapping("/submittedAirport")
public String post(@RequestParam("searchAirports") String value) {
  System.out.println("Selected Value="+value)  
  return "index";
}
```

Sample JSP:

```
...
<form action="">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input name="searchAirports" id="searchAirports"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/> 
</form>
```

On Submitting the form, I was able get the selected value in the post method

```
Selected Value=A, B, C, D
```